# Clean the URL like of Google+

Tags: database, apache, url, localhost, google-plus

Sorry for so brief title. I am wondering how Google+ makes user URLs so clean. I mean like :

https://plus.google.com/+PuruVijay

Would take me to my page. I want to know how is that + after/ was put and how it loaded the corresponding page. I want a database to get the URL. The URL actually should have been like

Plus.Google. com/user?id=134566

Looking for a good answer please help

Edit:
An example is of this page's URL

Comment: This is way too broad without any details about your server setup. There are many ways to accomplish this but it depends on what you are using.

Comment: @whrrgarbl its localhost Apache till now but if it can be done with php or JavaScript, it would be really good

Comment: Ok, that is very important to know. You should edit your question to reflect that and add a tag so people can find it.

Comment: Have you read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like that... just you need to create folder of name
e.g. http://yoursite.com/*PuruVijay*

here PuruVijay is folder you need to create in you Website directory.. and put index file in that folder

Comment: Horrible idea. I can't just create a whole folder for each user. I need to get value from database only

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say you are using an Apache server. The typical way to handle URL manipulations like this is the module `mod_rewrite`, which you can find documentation on [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). This uses regular expressions to match URLs and direct to another. For example, a rule for /~user to /u/user is

```
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]+)/?(.*)    /u/$1/$2
```

For the Google+ example, you say you want to translate from `/+PuruVijay` to  `/user?id=134566`. This will be a little more complicated because the URL as given does not include the User ID, so you will have to retrieve the number some other way. You can however use `mod_rewrite` to redirect to `/user?name=+PuruVijay`. This would look something like (*not tested!*)

```
RewriteRule    ^/\+(.*)    /user?id=$1
```

Then, your `user` page can get the `id` parameter and look it up in the database to display the correct page, while allowing the user to type in an easy-to-remember URL.

As far as mapping `PuruVijay` to `134566`, Google+ requires the custom URLs to be unique, so there is a 1-1 correspondence between the handle `PuruVijay` and the user ID number `134566`. Otherwise it would be impossible to look up a specific ID number given a custom URL. Your site would have to place a similar restriction if you decide to allow custom handles like this.

Comment: Actually I wanna know how to convert user.php?id=45677 to /users/3556543. Don't take id seriously

Comment: In that case you would just switch the rule around, something like `^/user.php?id=(\d+)    /users/$1` to map /user.php?id=1234 to /users/1234. But to have the browser go from /user.php?id=1234 to /users/5678 you will need to do some server side processing to find the other number and then have it redirect to the new page.